# OpenPDF - absolute positioning

Tags: openpdf

My goal is to generate a PDF according predefined template. I started with 
https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/ and I am evaluating https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/ (iText 2.1.7 fork) at this moment.

This is my desired template:

[image]

There are two pictures side by side. There is a text below the right picture that is aligned to picture boundaries and it can wrap if it is longer than the picture itself.

Then there will be several paragraphs. Their vertical position may be adjusted by paragraph size.

Ideal API would have method where I can set the text, alignment, cursors position and width and it would render it within the box.

My current code:

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent ();
    addBorder(document, cb);
    addPicture(document);
    addPhoto(document, "This is some text –\ncontinued.\nLast line", cb);
    document.close();
}

private static void addPicture(Document document) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Image image = Image.getInstance("picture.png");
    image.scalePercent (40.0f);
    image.setAbsolutePosition(90, 650);
    document.add(image);
}

private static void addPhoto(Document document, String verse, PdfContentByte cb) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Image image = Image.getInstance("another_picture.png");
    image.scalePercent (30.0f);
    image.setAbsolutePosition(380, 650);
    document.add(image);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(verse);
    document.add(paragraph);

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
    cb.beginText();
    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, verse, 380, 650, 0);
    cb.endText ();
}

private static void addBorder(Document doc, PdfContentByte cb) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    cb.rectangle (doc.left(), doc.bottom(), doc.right() - doc.left (), doc.top() - doc.bottom ());
    cb.stroke();
}
```

I was able to position both pictures where I wanted thanks to `setAbsolutePosition()` method. But there is no similar method for `Paragraph`. I found `PdfContentByte` class that can position the text according to my needs but it lacks basic `Paragraph` features like text wrapping or translating new line characters.

How can I achieve precise positioning with PDF? I want to reuse existing code instead of calculating width of each sentence and splitting it myself.

Comment: Ok. But openpdf uses itext API. I am learning from itext articles.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Does current iText support my intention? I hate that a pricing is missing on your site. I requested a quote few months ago but nobody responded.

Comment: Looking at the screen shot, I'd say that iText 7 can perfectly create such a PDF, but it's not clear to me what you mean when you talk about a *predefined template*. Are you talking about an AcroForm? Are you talking about an HTML template? How dynamic should the template be, for instance: what happens with the template if the images have an unexpected size?

Comment: As for a quote, the price depends on the use. If we don't know if you are using iText on one or more servers (that can be counted), or if you are using iText in the context of a SaaS application (where you can't count servers), or if you're using iText in a Desktop app, or if you're using iText in an OEM product,... we can't provide a price. Putting prices online is difficult, because some developers then order 1 perpetual server for the price of a single OEM server (ignoring the fact that you need to buy a large volume of servers to get that price).

Comment: I mean that a designer creates a visual template with instructions where to place an image and where to place some text. And I will implement a code that generates PDF that is close to what designer created.

Comment: I have received an email "Thank you for your iText sales inquiry" on 17.09.17 that I will be contacted shortly. It has not happened yet.

Comment: I informed our sales people about this. Will keep bumping it in our Slack until you get a reply. :)

Comment: They'll have a look.

Comment: Clear description, source code and down vote ..

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, wasn't me. Did you hear from our sales team?

Comment: Julie sent me a confusing email three das ago. It cited some Patrick's quote.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I have the same issue (but just with positioning different paragraphs of text.) did you ever get this situation sorted out?

Comment: I have moved to HTML and a service that can generate PDF from it.